# P-adic order of a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be a prime number and $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{0}$. We define the $p$-adic order of $x$ (notation: $ord_{p}(x))$ as the greatest exponent $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $p^{\alpha}|x$. 
Now show that $ord_{p}(ab)=ord_{p}(a)+ord_{p}(b)$ for every $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Intuitively, this equality seems very obvious to me. However, I don't know how to give a proper proof of it. Can someone give a hint on how to start solving this problem, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start with the factorizations of $a,b$ as $a=p^mz,b=p^nw$ where $z,w$ not divisible by $p.$

Comment: @simp Did you figure out how to use the hint to show the ord formula?